# Fetch Query Parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to fetch authorization code from the URL . It is present as a query string parameters.

When I run the belowo URL

https://XXX.authenticaion.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sb!t113

It redirects to 
http://localhost:8080/?code=8wFgU1GJo3

I need to parse the localhost URL and fetch the code.

Please help on how to retrieve the code

**Code :**

```
 const url = 'https://XXX.authenticaion.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sb!t113'
     const config = {
      method: "GET"   
    };
    const response = await fetch(url ,config);

    console.log('Response Text...............'+response.text())
```

Comment: Do you need to parse the localhost url to extract the code parameter?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: But the problem is,its a redirect URL I know the locla host URL only after the first URL is run

Comment: Then you're trying to fetch it from the current page query string, not parse the URL

Comment: that's right.. When I run the first  URL ,it redirects to the local host URL from there I pick up the code..

Comment: Then look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could use plain js `URL` web api to create URL object and then get the `code` value.

```js
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/?code=8wFgU1GJo3'
const code = new URL(url).searchParams.getAll('code')

console.log(code)
```

Comment: But my problem is,its a redirect URL so how do I retrieve after running the first URL.

Comment: Then you should get url from the localhost after redirection in some way for example you could try `window.location.href`, and then you get query string as in answer.